# byRef argument type mismatch help anyone

Tags: vb6

My supervisor asked me to debug a recent program in vb6. I only have basic knowledge in vb. When I try to run the program a byref argument mismatch is shown. Can anyone help me with this. I'll appreciate any comments.

```
Public Sub S2_Sort()

'loop day
For dCnt = 1 To UBound(S2.Day())
    ReDim S2.Day(dCnt).tList(0)

    'loop shift
    For tCnt = 1 To UBound(TaskID())
        ReDim Preserve S2.Day(dCnt).tList(tCnt)
        ReDim Preserve S2.Day(dCnt).tList(tCnt).sList(0)
        'dicShift.RemoveAll

        'loop task
        For sCnt = 1 To UBound(Shift())
            ReDim Preserve S2.Day(dCnt).tList(tCnt).sList(sCnt)
            ReDim Preserve S2.Day(dCnt).tList(tCnt).sList(sCnt).TaskRecList(0)

            'query with paramaters for project, datetime, and taskid
             strQuery = "SELECT * FROM PROD_DB WHERE PROJECT_ID = '" & inpProject & "'" & _
                    " AND " & GetTimestamp(S2.Day(dCnt).DayVal, Shift(sCnt).NextDay, True, Shift(sCnt).StartHour, _
                    Shift(sCnt).HourLen) & _
                    " AND TASK_ID = '" & TaskID(tCnt).TaskID & "'" & _
                    " ORDER BY START_TIME, TASK_ID"
            Set rstInfo = AdoConn.Execute(strQuery)

            If Not (rstInfo.EOF And rstInfo.BOF) Then
                rstInfo.MoveFirst
                wCnt = 0
                Do Until rstInfo.EOF
                    wCnt = wCnt + 1
                    ReDim Preserve S2.Day(dCnt).tList(tCnt).sList(sCnt).TaskRecList(wCnt)
                    'save the records to a arraylist datarecord
                    Call SetDataRecord(rstInfo, wCnt)

                    'then compute, get the work time number and list it on stLIst
                    S2.Day(dCnt).tList(tCnt).sList(sCnt).Val = S2_Compute(S2.Day(dCnt).tList(tCnt).sList(sCnt).TaskRecList(wCnt), S2.Day(dCnt).tList(tCnt).sList(sCnt).Val)
                    S2.Day(dCnt).tList(tCnt).Val = S2_Compute(S2.Day(dCnt).tList(tCnt).sList(sCnt).TaskRecList(wCnt), S2.Day(dCnt).tList(tCnt).Val)
                    'S2.Day(dCnt).tList(tCnt).MstUnit = DataRecord(X).MeasurementUnit
                    'S2.Day(dCnt).tList(tCnt).Cost = DataRecord(X).Cost
                    S2.Day(dCnt).tList(tCnt).ResourceName = S2.Day(dCnt).tList(tCnt).ResourceName + S2.Day(dCnt).tList(tCnt).sList(sCnt).TaskRecList(wCnt).ResourceName
                    S2.Day(dCnt).Val = S2_Compute(S2.Day(dCnt).tList(tCnt).sList(sCnt).TaskRecList(wCnt), S2.Day(dCnt).Val)

                    rstInfo.MoveNext
                Loop
            End If
            Set rstInfo = Nothing
        Next sCnt 'Next Shift
    Next tCnt 'Next Task
Next dCnt 'Next Day
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please do in some kind your homework and add what you have tried and where you failed.

Comment: i really dont know what i am doing in here. if you can understand this code can u describe what the variable tCnt and what the S2.day means? all i've done here is change the provider and conditoion the data that has a null value. other than that i dont know what really happens in this program.

Comment: basically query with paramaters for project, datetime, and taskid is where the error pops up. and i dont really get this part of the program.

Comment: You were asked to debug program. In VB6 IDE, you can use F8 to step through your code - this way you should see, at what line you get the error. We here cannot debug your code after all.

Comment: so basically the first yellow portion when i run at F8 will be the first error of this program? if there's any part of the code you want to see tell me so i cant post it here. thanks in advance btw

Comment: Perhaps you should tell your supervisor that you don't know how to do the task you've been assigned, rather than asking the internet to do it for you?

Comment: The S2 construct is quite complicated: it is a Class or Type with a Day array as Property. The type of an element of the Day array is itself again a Class (or Type) that again has an array as its property (tList). This goes on for at least two levels further.

Comment: Public sCnt, tCnt, wCnt, dCnt As Integer Public 
S2 As udt_DTSS_Project

 hear are the variable declaration that is used

Answer (score 1):

The ByRef argument mismatch error is usually a simple mismatch between the type of an argument that is passsed to a Sub that expects a different type. Your variable declarations are not present in the code, so it is impossible to tell.

The only call to another Sub I see is the `Call SetDataRecord(rstInfo, wCnt)` line.

So check the type of rstInfo and wCnt against the type of arguments that SetDataRecord expects.

Comment: Public sCnt, tCnt, wCnt, dCnt As Integer 
Public S2 As udt_DTSS_Project

hear are the variable declaration that is used.

Comment: If the code line really reads `Public sCnt, tCnt, wCnt, dCnt As Integer` then contrary to what you would think, only dCnt is an Integer, the variables before that are Variants. Pass a Variant to a Sub or Function that expects an Integer and you will get the error you encountered.

Comment: I've already declared the sCnt, tCnt, wCnt as interger. Still im getting the by ref argument mismatch in the code above.

Comment: So your code literally reads: `Dim sCnt as Integer` <br/> `Dim tCnt as Integer` <br/> `Dim wCnt as Integer`? Then the variables have been correctly declared as Integers. Now chek if any Sub or Functions they are passed to expect Variants.

Comment: yes I've declared them as integer individually. what sub or functions did you mean sir? after changing it individually, i still got the error in the "nextday" variable i guess. wherein nextday is declare to as a private type. from a global variable module.

Comment: Sorry, I have no new light to shed on this problem.